# Multisite: merging two subsites in the main site

Tags: multisite, database, mysql

I have a multisite:

example.com = example.com/ar/

example.com/es/

example.com/en/

example.com/ba/

I need to merge 2 and 4 into 1 the main site without losing the post

Ending with only 2 webs: the main site and 1 subsite.

example, com= example.com/ar/

example.com/es/

The database is MariaDB

Any tutorial on how to do this?

I will do it on a new server

Thanks

Irene

Answer (score 0):

Backup your database. Then Tools, Export from source site. Then switch to target site. Tools, Import. You may have to install the plugin (it will prompt you).

Lots of googles/bings/ducks on how to do this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Which plugin? I ask here because I didn't find info in G, I didn't find anything about merging only a part of a multisite.

Comment: Not a plugin. Standard option in Tools menu. Lots of articles on how to combine two sites into one (basically: export from source; import into target). Merging will add to database, not replace it.